# How to import Prestashop live to Wampserver?

Tags: wamp, prestashop, wampserver, prestashop-1.6

I want to do some templating on my website, so I'm trying to backup my online Prestashop to my computer with Wampserver.

My website is running on Prestashop 1.6.1.7

This is what I done :

1. Export sql database
2. Download FTP files
3. Create a new database and import my DB with PHPMyAdmin (Wampserver 3.2.3)
4. Add VirtualHost in Documents/Test Add www files in /Documents/Test
5. Change ps_shop_url :
   domain:localhost
   domain_ssl:localhost
   physical_uri:http://localhost/test/
6. Change rules in /Documents/Test/config/settings.inc.php file :

```
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'localhost:3306');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'mydbname');
define('_DB_USER_', 'root');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', '');
define('_DB_PREFIX_', 'ps_');
define('_MYSQL_ENGINE_', 'InnoDB');
define('_PS_CACHING_SYSTEM_', 'CacheMemcache');
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '0');
define('_COOKIE_KEY_', 'I didn't touch it');
define('_COOKIE_IV_', 'I didn't touch it');
define('_PS_CREATION_DATE_', 'I didn't touch it');
define('_PS_VERSION_', '1.6.1.7');
define('_RIJNDAEL_KEY_', 'I didn't touch it');
define('_RIJNDAEL_IV_', 'I didn't touch it');
define('_PS_DIRECTORY_', '/../../');
```

But http://localhost/test/ returns a 404 not found :(

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .htaccess int the root.
and do not rewrite url in local, so desactivate it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

**physical_uri** should be only the path after the base URL,
so in your case just use **/test/**

If you are still facing issues after that, go in backoffice and regenerate .htaccess by saving in SEO&URL section.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Melvita and @user3256843

I can login tu back office and saves URL rules.
Now, all URL are live.

Just a little "problem", my local website is very looong to load and some CSS rules seems to be broken.

But all pages are 90% identical as live website.

Thank you very much folks !